# JavaScript Fetch Unable to return value calling other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am unable to get any value when I called `logger()` even though I managed to get value when I logged in the `logger()` I do not know what is wrong with it.

```
 fetch(apiURL, setting)
  .then(loadRes)
  .then(logger)
  
  
  function loadRes (res){
    return res.json();
  }
  
  
  function logger (reply){
    let stringReply =  JSON.stringify(reply);
    console.log("The JSON String " + stringReply) // The logged result is "The JSON String [{"Id":1}]"
    return stringReply;
  }
```

But when I tried to call it again with the code below

```
var logTest = logger();
console.log(logTest);  // The logged result is "The JSON String undefined"
```

Basically I cannot get it to return any value even though I have managed to call it.

Logged Results

```
The JSON String undefined

The JSON String [{"Id":1}]
```

Comment: are you sure you the url and setting are both correct and you can get result back from the api? check that from the network tab

Comment: Yes I have managed to get response from it. But when I called the function again it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is async. The line `console.log(logTest)` will be executed before the fetch promise is fulfilled.
Try adding some `console.log(1)` `console.log(2)` to get an idea what is called in what order.

To make this work as intended and use the return value of an async function synchronously , you can use asyc/await.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
function loadRes (res){
    console.log('loadres called')
    return res.json();
  }

function logger (reply){
    let stringReply =  JSON.stringify(reply);
    console.log("The JSON String " + stringReply) 
    return stringReply;
  }

function logger (reply){
    console.log('logger called', reply)
    let stringReply =  JSON.stringify(reply);
    console.log("The JSON String " + stringReply) // The logged result is "The JSON String [{"Id":1}]"
    return stringReply;
  }

async function myAsyncFunction(apiURL, setting) {
  console.log('async function called')
  const result = await fetch(apiURL, setting).then(json => json.json())
  return result
}

myAsyncFunction('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(result => logger(result))
```

Comment: I have gotten an error ```Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client```  It might be due to the async function which somehow interfere with it

Comment: Yes you are right. It is likely that the code finished executing before it managed to obtain a value from fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
var logTest = logger();

console.log(logTest);
```

Maybe You need pass parameters to logger("{"something":1}")

Answer (score 0):

I think you need study more about `async` and `promise` first.

```
var logTest = logger();
console.log(logTest);
```

here you only call `logger` without any parameter, enhance `undefined` logged, and it's nothing related with your above `fetch` operation. you can only get response within thenable callback

```
fetch().then().then()
```